# Exception to negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Is it possible to define an exception to a negative lookahead?

Example: match any sequence of characters that's not followed by `//` but allow fragments like `http://` and `https://`

My example is much more complicated but it essentially comes down to this.

Comment: `.*(?!(?<!https?:)//)`? (not followed by // unless preceded by http(s)?)

Comment: Depends on if the `http://` needs to be in the match, but you're right in that `(.(?!(?<!http:|https:)//))*` is more in line with the question. However, the actual requirements are a bit vague a.t.m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(http://[^/]*|https://[^/]*|(?!//).)*
```

Try this.This will skip the two you want.

or

```
(https?://|(?!//).)*
```

Comment: Nice thought, I'd write it as `(https?://|.(?!//))*` though.

Comment: Hmm... Why condition `(?!//)` after consume `.`? It will be incorrect.

Comment: @vks: You copied Wrikken's regex directly without the escaping, so I assume you are specifying raw regex. And you don't need to escape `/` in Python anyway.

Comment: @nhahtdh at regex101.com too we need to escape `/` ?

Comment: @vks: No you don't. You need to click on Python mode.

Comment: Well, although in some languages (and or even some methods in some languages) there's a default delimiter `/`, and literal `/`'s in the regex need to be escaped, it's far from all. As the OP doesn't state any specific language, so I would think an unescaped answer would be best, with possibly a comment that 'in some implementations'  the `/`'s should be escaped. Makes it more portable, and more readable ;)

Comment: @Wrikken: `//` is more readable than `\/\/`, IMHO. `/` is only escaped in languages using `/` as delimiter (e.g. JavaScript, PCRE, Perl), but in PCRE and Perl, you can even specify something else as delimiter.

Comment: How you wrote an answer without understanding the question :-) ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj we dont know the input,but we know what OP wants. :)

Comment: Thank you! I was also trying an alternate construct for a lookahead and a lookbehind (i.e. not followed by `//` OR preceded by `https?:`) but it seems like there isn't such a thing. :)